# How to list all districts of a city showing profits every month

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to list all the districts of a city showing profits every month.

I am not knowing how to tie the count values ​​of the products with the month in the subquery.

Could someone give me a hand?

```
SELECT 
       districts.id,
       districts.name,
       mmonth.m10
FROM districts
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT 
       SUM(product_order.price_of_day * product_order.amount) AS m10
   FROM product_order
   INNER JOIN orders ON product_order.order_id = orders.id
   WHERE MONTH(orders.date_time) = 10 ) mmonth
INNER JOIN cities ON cities.id = districts.city_id
WHERE cities.id = 2;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8fb34/4

Look what I need.

```
| id |     name   | m10 | m11 | m12 |
------------------------------------
|  3 | district 3 | 730 | 360 | 453 |
------------------------------------
|  4 | district 4 | 730 | 250 | 856 |
-------------------------------------
```

How would I sum the months like this?

```
| id |     name   | m10 | m11 | m12 | total |
---------------------------------------------
|  3 | district 3 | 730 | 360 | 453 | 1543  |
---------------------------------------------
|  4 | district 4 | 730 | 250 | 856 | 1836  |
---------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Just return a GROUPED and ordered result. Handle issues of data display in the presentation layer/application-level code, if you have one (e.g. a bit of PHP)

Comment: You need to be looking at using `GROUP BY` as stated above, and the above question doesn't give enough details as to how an order is linked to a district (I accept the link to SQLFiddle but it's often nice to have it closer to hand).

Comment: I've just updated the code in my answer (was working in SQL Server), though the results don't quite match that which you have displayed above :-S

Comment: Thanks @talegna! How would I sum the months?

Comment: @Borre has already answered it but it would be the same for my method `SUM(product_order.price_of_day * product_order.amount) AS Total`

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

This should do it:

```
SELECT 
       districts.id,
       districts.name,
       SUM(IF(MONTH(orders.date_time) = 10, product_order.price_of_day * product_order.amount, 0)) AS m10,
       SUM(IF(MONTH(orders.date_time) = 11, product_order.price_of_day * product_order.amount, 0)) AS m11,
       SUM(IF(MONTH(orders.date_time) = 12, product_order.price_of_day * product_order.amount, 0)) AS m12,
       SUM(product_order.price_of_day * product_order.amount) AS total
FROM cities
LEFT JOIN districts ON cities.id = districts.city_id
LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.district_id = districts.id
LEFT JOIN product_order ON product_order.order_id = orders.id
WHERE cities.id = 2
GROUP BY districts.id;
```

Comment: thanks for the help. I had thought of something similar. The problem is that it returns the same value for all districts.

Comment: You are right, I must have misread. I updated my answer to reflect your question

Comment: Thanks @Borre! How would I sum the months?

Comment: Answer has been updated to contain the total for each district

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `GROUP BY` (see: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx)

```
SELECT
    [IdentifyingDataColumnName]
    ...
    ,[IdentifyingDataColumnName1]
    ,[CalculatedField] =  SUM(<column name(/s) / Calculation to sum>)
FROM
    Table 1
    LEFT JOIN 2
GROUP BY
    [IdentifyingDataColumnName]
    ...
    ,[IdentifyingDataColumnName1]
HAVING  
    SUM(<column name(/s) / Calculation to sum>) > 0
```

Having re-read your question (and realising I'd completely mis-read it!) you could do the following:

```
SELECT 
    districts.id
    ,districts.name
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(orders.date_time) = 10 THEN (product_order.price_of_day * product_order.amount) ELSE 0 END) AS m10
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(orders.date_time) = 11 THEN (product_order.price_of_day * product_order.amount) ELSE 0 END) AS m11
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(orders.date_time) = 12 THEN (product_order.price_of_day * product_order.amount) ELSE 0 END) AS m12
FROM 
    districts 
    INNER JOIN cities ON cities.id = districts.city_id
    INNER JOIN orders ON districts.id = orders.district_id
    INNER JOIN product_order ON product_order.order_id = orders.id
WHERE 
    cities.id = 2
GROUP BY 
    districts.id
    ,districts.name
```

Adding a total column couldn't be easier, you just remove the `CASE... WHEN... THEN... ELSE... END` and it will sum them all; the below code has also been modified to use a `LEFT JOIN` in order to ensure that should a district exist for the city without orders it will still be listed with monthly values of 0 (For more information see: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa178429(v=SQL.80).aspx)

```
SELECT 
    districts.id
    ,districts.name
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(orders.date_time) = 10 THEN (product_order.price_of_day * product_order.amount) ELSE 0 END) AS m10
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(orders.date_time) = 11 THEN (product_order.price_of_day * product_order.amount) ELSE 0 END) AS m11
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(orders.date_time) = 12 THEN (product_order.price_of_day * product_order.amount) ELSE 0 END) AS m12
    ,SUM(product_order.price_of_day * product_order.amount) AS Total
FROM 
    districts 
    INNER JOIN cities ON cities.id = districts.city_id
    LEFT JOIN orders ON districts.id = orders.district_id
    LEFT JOIN product_order ON product_order.order_id = orders.id
WHERE 
    cities.id = 2
GROUP BY 
    districts.id
    ,districts.name
```